# Error in assign(".popath", popath, .BaseNamespaceEnv) : cannot change value of locked binding for '.popath'

Tags: r, rprofile

I'm a new R user, and I've changed the default path of library package for my convenience, but I ended up getting the the error every time I start Rstudio:

"Error in assign(".popath", popath, .BaseNamespaceEnv) : 
  cannot change value of locked binding for '.popath'"

Question: Is it okay to ignore it? or should I do something to fix that?

*I changed the default path of library package by naming a new user variable (Variable name: R_LIBS_USER; variable path: C:...)

Answer (score 0):

It ends up that I forget to delete the R.history file when I modify the start up R script file but decided to retract it back.